# Math Problem Help || Trig (Updated picture)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, area

So I got the following math problem I solved but I'm not confident with my answer. My answer was 32.

The question is to **find the area** of the following:
http://i.gyazo.com/c00c5afc60c33ebc934333e2b0d755a6.png

UPDATED PICTURE BELOW (Because the old one was hurting people's eyes)
http://i.gyazo.com/a046efd5e588148ac5146329a5be438e.png

Comment: What on earth is going on in that picture? Should that angle be $60$ degrees or $90$ degrees?

Comment: Is the actual shape some sort of trapezoid?

Comment: This hurts my eyes.

Comment: Yes, it is a trapezoid.

Comment: Sorry, but this is too funny.

Comment: Maybe this is non-euclidean geometry hehe

Comment: Lol what are you guys talking about?

Comment: Your drawing shows a square, therefore with 4 right angles (=90°), one of which is labelled 60°. For some people (me included) this is kind of funny...

Comment: Yea that was the confusion. But I fixed the picture. Only 2 angles are 90 degrees.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the first picture. There's no reason to assume any angle is right unless explicitly told so.

Comment: Yea I know, some people assumed it was a square and got confused by '60degrees'. Anyways, I would like to get passed that and solve this problem, it's kinda tricky and fun :)

Comment: Hint: Divide it into triangle and rectangle and use sin 60° and cos 60° to calculate its sides.

Comment: The answer I get is $21 \sqrt(3)$

Comment: To lmsteffan: I get the same result $21 \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First simplify the square roots: $\sqrt{96}=4\sqrt 6$, and $\sqrt{24}=2\sqrt 6$.

Second, recognize that the top and bottom sides of the quadrilateral are parallel, so this is a trapezoid. You have the bottom base, so all you need for the area are the top base and the height.

Third, you see a $30°$-$60°$-$90°$ triangle in the lower right hand corner (if you add an auxiliary line from the top right corner of the trapezoid). The height of the trapezoid is the leg opposite the $60°$ angle, and the top base is the bottom base minus the leg opposite the $30°$ angle. You know the hypotenuse, $2\sqrt 6$. You can then find the legs of that triangle. (I get the bottom leg as $\sqrt 6$ and the height as $3\sqrt 2$. That makes the upper base $3\sqrt 6$.)

Can you finish up now? I get the area as $21\sqrt 3$.

$$A=\frac{b_1+b_2}2h$$
$$=\frac{3\sqrt 6+4\sqrt 6}2\cdot 3\sqrt 2$$
$$=21\sqrt 3$$

Comment: wow nice explanation, I just revised my math and realized I did everything wrong. This is very helpful